# Why tensorflow 2.0.0(official) is much slower than tensorflow 2.0.0-beta1?(both are cpu verison)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, tensorflow2.0

Under ubuntu 18.04, using PyCharm as the IDE, running the same code, just a 3-linear layer network, to train an RL agent to play `CartPole-v0` with OpenAI gym for 3000 steps.

With tensorflow 2.0beta1, it just cost 14 secs:

```py
TensorFlow Version:  2.0.0-beta1
num_actions:  2
obs_shape:  (4,)
2019-10-08 09:12:39.648644: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-10-08 09:12:39.669515: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2304000000 Hz
2019-10-08 09:12:39.669920: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x557b0e7eaaa0 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-10-08 09:12:39.669956: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2019-10-08 09:12:39.747755: W tensorflow/compiler/jit/mark_for_compilation_pass.cc:1483] (One-time warning): Not using XLA:CPU for cluster because envvar TF_XLA_FLAGS=--tf_xla_cpu_global_jit was not set.  If you want XLA:CPU, either set that envvar, or use experimental_jit_scope to enable XLA:CPU.  To confirm that XLA is active, pass --vmodule=xla_compilation_cache=1 (as a proper command-line flag, not via TF_XLA_FLAGS) or set the envvar XLA_FLAGS=--xla_hlo_profile.
res of test model:  0 [ 0.06576662 -0.00780154]
Before Training: 9 out of 200
losses each 1000 steps:  0.004245305
losses each 1000 steps:  0.002508364
losses each 1000 steps:  0.009408922
The total train time:  14.006552696228027
After Training: 200 out of 200
```

But when it comes to tensorflow 2.0official, exactly the same code, however the time cost is 18 times higher, which also really memory consuming almost kill my laptop:

```py
TensorFlow Version:  2.0.0
num_actions:  2
obs_shape:  (4,)
2019-10-08 09:24:19.170213: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-10-08 09:24:19.193118: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2304000000 Hz
2019-10-08 09:24:19.193366: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x564a84d34fb0 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-10-08 09:24:19.193384: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
res of test model:  0 [0. 0.]
Before Training: 8 out of 200
losses each 1000 steps:  0.037620276
losses each 1000 steps:  0.0022274784
losses each 1000 steps:  0.002310919
The total train time:  261.44773054122925
After Training: 123 out of 200
```

I don't know what the reason is, PyCharm or TensorFlow 2.0.
Note, both are tensorflow cpu version and eager mode.

Comment: Here is my training code: https://github.com/Huixxi/TensorFlow2.0-for-Deep-Reinforcement-Learning/blob/master/04_dueling.py

Comment: If you suspect PyCharm for the slower execution, you may try running the file in a Jupyter notebook or directly in the Python console.